# How to use a Python class as content of slicing brackets in Numpy

Tags: python, slice

In Python you can use a tuple as the content of the brackets

```
matrix = np.zeros((3, 4, 8, 9))
coords = (2, 3)
element = matrix[coords]
```

I would like to do the same with a custom class `CustomDuple`

```
duple = CustomDuple(2, 3)
matrix[duple]
```

But I receive the `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Is this currently implemented in Python? Without using a method like `CustomDuple.to_tuple(self)->tuple`

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Python in general. Every class that defines `__getitem__` (`numpy.ndarray`, in this case) decides what arguments it will accept.

Comment: In the end, you need to convert your objects to tuples in order to use them as indexes. As you read for yourself, numpy only accepts certain type of objects as index input.

Comment: `foo[bar]` is implemented by `foo.__getitem__(bar)`, no matter what type `bar` has.

Comment: The only thing Python does is handle slice syntax to generate the correct `slice` object(s) to pass to `__getitem__` when appropriate. (E.g., `foo[1:3]` is implemented by `foo.__getitem__(slice(1, 3, None))`.)

Comment: I've provided an answer below, but the real question here is: what do you need this class to be able to do, that a tuple can't? A tuple is a very efficient data type in Python, weighing things down with your own class isn't ideal, and there's probably better ways to solve the actual problem you're trying to solve - which you're not telling us about.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any example code to show what `CustomDuple` actually is or does, but given that you want to be able to use it directly as a `tuple`, we have to assume it at least is most of what a tuple is.

Having said that, inheritance seems like the best solution. However, the tuple `__init__` won't allow you to pass more than one argument, even if you subclass it. You can create a factory method to produce a new tuple though, which could take any number of arguments (which is what you seem to be trying to achieve):

```
import numpy as np


class CustomDuple(tuple):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, *args):
        if len(args) > 0:
            # this is the behaviour you seem to want (for any size tuple)
            return cls([*args])
        else:
            try:
                # try and stay close to the normal constructor behaviour
                return cls(*args)
            except TypeError:
                # however, if a single non-iterable was passed, wrap it
                return cls([*args])

    def first_element(self):
        return None if not len(self) else self[0]


duple = CustomDuple.new(2, 3)  # creating a duple tuple with its factory method
matrix = np.zeros((3, 4, 8, 9))
print(matrix[duple])
print(duple.first_element())  # your duple can have additional behaviour
```

Note that this wouldn't allow you to call `CustomDuple.new([1])` and expect `([1],)` as a result - you'd get `(1,)`. You could of course just remove the bit of code that tries to stay as close as possible to `tuple()` for `CustomDuple.new()`:

```
class CustomDuple(tuple):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, *args):
        return cls([*args])
```

However, although either solution works as you ask, I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you have very, very good reasons not to want to use a normal `tuple`.

After all, you can just create it like this:

```
duple = tuple([2, 3])
```

User @blckknght asked in the comments why not override `__new__` - you definitely can, if you are OK with specifically passing 2 arguments, instead of any number:

```
class CustomDuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, arg1, arg2):
        return super().__new__(cls, [arg1, arg2])
```

Note however, that neither of these then work:

```
duple = CustomDuple()
duple = CustomDuple([1, 2])
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to name your method `__new__`? I'd also assume that a `Duple` is a 2-tuple, so worrying about other numbers of arguments is probably unnecessary.

Comment: There is a very good reason: `__new__` would overwrite the class' `__new__` magic method. These get called for specific purposes, `__new__` is called when a new instance of the class gets created, just before `__init__` (another magical method) is called. You should only overwrite dunder / magic methods if you need to override that behaviour. In this case I picked `new` because it gets called when you do want `__new__` to be called for the tuple, but you can't just override it - so, you call the factory method and `tuple.__new__` and `tuple.__init__` will get called.

Comment: Also note that forcing `CustomDuple` to be a 2-tuple is simply a matter of replacing `*args` with `arg1, arg2` - but I don't think that was the point of the question. Also, for the given purpose n-tuples do make sense.

Comment: But that's my question, why aren't you overriding `__new__`? Isn't that exactly what the questioner wants?

Comment: Ah, you were asking why I didn't *name* it that, which is what I responded to - but you're right could indeed override `__new__` (with different arguments) if you don't care about a variable number of arguments.

Comment: You can also handle the variable argument case in `__new__` if you want to, just do whatever translation is needed and pass it on to `super().__new__`.